# running python code, to use sextractor with more than one image file

Tags: python, loops

I have written piece of code which runs sextractor from python, however I only know how to do this for one file, and i need to loop it over 62 files. Im not sure how i would go about doing this. I have attached my code bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

`# build a catalog using sextractor on des image here`

```
sys.path.append('/home/fitsfiles')     #not sure if this does anything/is correct

def sex(image, output, sexdir='/home/sextractor-2.5.0', check_img=None,config=None, l=None) : 
  '''Construct a sextractor command and run it.'''
  #creates a sextractor line e.g sex img.fits -catalog_name -checkimage_name
  q="/home/fitsfiles/"+ "01" +".fits"
  com = [ "sex ", q, " -CATALOG_NAME " + output]
  s0=''
  com = s0.join(com)
  res = os.system(com)
  return res

img_name=sys.argv[0]
output=img_name[0:1]+'_star_catalog.fits'
t=sex(img_name,output)

print '----done !---'
```

so this code produces a command in my main terminal of, sex /home/fitsfiles/01.fits -CATALOG_NAME g_star_catalog.fits

which successfully produces a star catalogue as I want.

However I want my code to to this for 62 fits files and change the name of star_catalog.fits depending upon which fitsfile is being used. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is gross, what are you developing?

Comment: im trying to make a python code which will run Sextractor with multiple image files, so I can have a variety of star catalogue which I can can then use in my other code which I have working to interpret data about a telescope.  unfortunately I have so many image files i cant manually change the code each time i want to run it. im just not familiar with importing files into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could approach this.  Let's assume you want to run your script as something like

```
python extract_stars.py /home/fitsfiles/*.fits
```

Then, you could try something like this:

```
for arg in len(sys.argv):
    filename = arg.split('/')[-1].strip('.fits')
    t = sex(arg, filename +'_star_catalog.fits')
    # Whatever else
```

This assumes that you remove the line in `sex` that reformats the input filename.  Also, you do not need to append the fits directory to your path.

The alternative approach is, if you do not plan to do anything else in python, you could write a bash script which would really simplify the task.

And, as a side note, you if you had asked this question more generally (ie, I wish to apply a function I wrote to a number of input files) and without reference to a rather uncommonly used application, you would have likely received an answer much more quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have managed to change my code to get it working with your above help.

I am new to posting problems online so thanks for the advice, and next time I will be more general. :)

Answer (score 1):

The community has now developed some python wrappers which allow you to run sextractor as if it was a python command. These are: pysex, sewpy and astromatic_wrapper.

The good thing about sextractor wrappers is that allow you to write much cleaner code without the need of defining extra functions, invoking os commands or having the configuration files and the outputfiles on your machine. Moreover, the output can be an astropy table, a pandas dataframe or a numpy array.

For your specific case, you could use [pysex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysex/) and do:

```
import pysex
import glob

filelist = glob.glob('/directory/*.fits')

for fitsfile in filelist:
    cat = pysex.run(fitsfile, params=['X_IMAGE', 'Y_IMAGE', 'FLUX_APER'],
    conf_args={'PHOT_APERTURES':5})
    print cat['FLUX_APER']
```